# remove unwanted ads and download manager from chrome in mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions

how to remove unwanted ads and the download manager which comes on google search result page. I have been trying to remove from chrome extention manager, but it doesn't seems to be there. also I have cleared all cache, removed browser history and cookies. these all doesn't go. Please help

Comment: You should post an image of what you are describing.  There are many methods for creating/displaying/injecting ads... An image would help us tell which is present in your case.

Comment: sorry, I am unable to attach image. Super user doesn't allows to attach images while your reputation is 10 or more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the wrong place asking this question.

I'll answer it though:
You can't remove something from the webpage, you can block practically anything however, with extensions like adblock/flashblock etc.

If you don't like the ads on google search page, use a different search engine.

Comment: but such ads should not be at higher websites such as google, ebay, flipkart, etc. is there no other solution instead of using adblock?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "such" ads. Non-intrusive advertising is a very common practice on those websites. If you're seeing some inappropriate ads, chances are you installed some 3rd party software that puts those ads in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) plugin from Google Chrome Store. Check your browser plugins, maybe you already installed some unwanted plugins:

Right side of your browser 3 line > Tools > Plugins

or

Write this to address line: `chrome://extensions/`

Comment: but those unwanted plugins I can't see in extension manager. what should i do?

Comment: http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Try out this application.

Comment: I am unable to find out such application which is being installed. how to get rid of that, totally stucked and very annoying